# Consume rest xml file in java spring-boot

Tags: java, xml, rest, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project in which I need to consume xml file through REST.
I just want to retrieve payload of my REST message as an xml file and store it locally.

On the internet, there are many tutorials to consume and convert xml file into java object, thanks to Jersey mainly.
Nevertheless, I do not want to convert this xml file into java object; I just need to recover the xml and store it.

I guess it will look like below :

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void post(...) {
    //retrieve payload of my xml rest message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@POST` is not a spring annotation but Jersey one.

With Spring annotations it would be something like this:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class YourController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/requestpath",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String home(@RequestBody byte[] requestBody) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "target.filename.xml";
        Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), requestBody);
        return "<message>OK</message>";
    }

}
```

Comment: @LaverteJean great! feel free to accept the answer if this resolved the issue.